# Run php scripts in ubuntu as deamon one time and on every bootup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, daemon

I have a simple question that I couldn't find an answer for on the web or on StackOverflow.

I have two PHP scripts that I would like to run as daemon (not every x seconds/days).

Now I want to run them manually.  I would also like them to run every time the server reboots.

What is the best practice for doing this?

If in your answer you are suggesting to use `/etc/init.d/` please explain how this is done.

Comment: I can't quite make sense of your request to run your scripts as a daemon and also to run them manually the way it's written.  Do you want to have a daemon running but also be able to run a second copy of the script manually and have that one finish?

Comment: No i want to run it from deamon now, but if the machine will restart it should run automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with cronjob.

```
@reboot  php -f /var/scripts/script.php
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the cronjob answer, which I would suggest, you can also do this inside of `/etc/rc.local`. If the script stays running, or runs for a period of time, you may want to fork it with `&` :

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/script.php &
exit 0
```

Is how the line would appear in your `/etc/rc.local` file

*Note:* added the exit 0 to show you want the line above the exit call).